# Why my nav-item don't go at the top of the window?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put a navbar with a navbar-brand to my website. There is a problem, it looks like my picture prevent my nav-items to go on the top of the window. Here is a picture of the problem :
[image]

When I remove the navbar-brand, the items are going at the top (you can try it with my code below).

Here is my code :

```css
.logo_1 {
  width:9%; 
  height: auto;
}

.logo_nom {
  width: 14%;
  height: auto;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
}

.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #fafafc;
}
/* change the brand and text color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
    color: #369d4a !important;
}
/* change the link color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #369d4a !important;
}
/* change the color of active or hovered links */
.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: #2b5c35 !important;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    color:#369d4a;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
    background-color:#369d4a;
}
.navbar-custom .icon-bar {
    background-color:#369d4a;
}

@media (max-width: 1250px) { 
  .nav-item:hover {
    background-color: #5eb56f;
  }
}
.dropdown-item {
  color : #369d4a !important;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: #5eb56f !important;
  color: #2b5c35 !important;
}



@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .nav .nav-item .dropdown-menu{ display: none; }
  .nav .nav-item:hover .nav-link{ color: #fff;  }
  .nav .nav-item:hover .dropdown-menu{ display: block; }
  .nav .nav-item .dropdown-menu{ margin-top:0; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<!-- Début navbar -->
    <nav class="nav navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom navbar-dark" aria-label="Eighth navbar example">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <a class="navbar-brand">
          <img src="logo_no_text.png" alt="Logo" class="logo_1 img-responsive">
          <img src="nom_commerce.png" alt="Logo" class="logo_nom img-responsive">
          <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggle btn_small_screen float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" >
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link px-3" href="">Test 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link px-3" href="">Test 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link px-3" href="">Test 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Test 4 </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Test 4.1</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Test 4.2</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Test 4.3</a>
                </div>
            </li>          
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link px-3" href="">Test 5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div></div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Fin navbar -->
    <!-- Script -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a col-6 div outside your logos.

```
<div class="col-6">
    <a>
      <img
        src="https://www.logodesign.net/images/illustration-logo.png"
        alt="Logo"
        class="logo_1 img-responsive"
      />
      <img
        src="https://www.logodesign.net/images/illustration-logo.png"
        alt="Logo"
        class="logo_nom img-responsive"
      />
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggle btn_small_screen float-right"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
        aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Because there is a margin in the body by default, here is how you fix it:

```
html, body {
 margin:0;
}
```

Comment: No change after adding this :/